# Ajax form upload IE 9 Issue

Tags: ajax, file-upload, internet-explorer-9, multipartform-data, form-data

I have went to many solutions but didnt find any answer for the below problem.

Problem: To upload a file (eg. xls) through ajax on **ie 9**

Solution(works ie 10+ but not on 9): Using jquery, FormData, files  the ajax call can be implemented but in **IE 9** neither Files property works(work around exists) and Neither FormData(no work around) works.

What alternate way can be used instead of FormData.Also neither jquery's serialize works nor does serializeArray and i do not want to convert the file to be uploaded to json as my server side handling code(Spring MVC java) is not for json

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Form data or the Files property is not supported in IE9 http://caniuse.com/#search=formdata

I saw someone from this community using a 3rd-party library - Webshim, you might want to try it. Below are the links:

http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html#FileReader

https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/